# How to launch a link for an image in a list?

Tags: html

I have list items as follows:

```
<ul>
<li onclick="myAction();">
<h1>stuff</h1>
<img src="image.gif"/>
```

I want to add a rul to the img, I tried adding a href as an attribute of the img but when I click on the image myAction() gets invoked rather than the link loaded.

Thanks

Comment: "add a rul to the img". A whu?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the image a link, you have to wrap it in an anchor tag

```
<ul>
    <li onclick="myAction();">
        <h1>stuff</h1>
        <a href="http://website.com"><img src="image.gif" alt="" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Note that this will might cause an ugly blue border to appear around the image in question.

Comment: When I do this myAction() still gets invoked, how can I prevent it from getting invoked when the img is clicked but it is invoked when all other child elements of the li are clicked?

Comment: @Mungbeans you'll have to prevent the click  event from bubbling up to the `li` or check at the `li` event if the click came from the link.